# How do I make <td> elements stay in place when the screen is zoomed in or out?

Tags: html, css

```
<div>
 <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="standard-table standard-table-mini" 
 summary="Object Table" style="padding-left: 224px; padding-right: 50px;">
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <th align="center" style="right-padding:10px;"><b>Action</b></th>
     <th align="left"><b>Components</b></th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
<tbody>
 <tr class="even">
  <td align="left" style="width: 550px;>
   <div class="field">//some code here to enter radio button as input</div>
  </td>

  <td align="center">
   <div class="field">//some code here to populate components when radio button is selected</div>
  </td>

  <td align="right" style="display: block;" id ="somelabel"> //this is initially not displayed and will only be displayed when Radio button8 is selected
   <input type="number">//some code here to enter labels and input
  </td>

 </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

This is what it looks like at 100% zoomed in: [image]

This is what it looks kike when the last radio button is selected at 100% zoomed in: [image]

This is what I want it to look like (this is when its 67% zoomed out)[image]
And i want the middle and right `<td>` element to stay in its place even when I zoom in and out. I am not allowed to change the implementation to css flexbox so, it will be great if I can work something with `position` `width` or something like that. Very new to HTML/CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Try not to use those in the parent object:

`td align="left" style="width: 60%"`

or

```
td align="center" position: absolute; top: 20%; left: 60%;position: relative
```

Comment: sorry what? could you please write it as code, your syntax confused me

Answer (score 0):

this one is fixed to the left component

```html
<div>
 <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="standard-table standard-table-mini" 
 summary="Object Table" style="padding-left: 224px; padding-right: 50px;">
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <th align="center" style="right-padding:10px;"><b>Action</b></th>
     <th align="left"><b>Components</b></th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
<tbody>
 <tr class="even">
  <td align="left" style="width: 60%">
   <div class="field">//some code here to enter radio button as input</div>
  </td>

  <td align="center">
   <div class="field">//some code here to populate components when radio button is selected</div>
  </td>

  <td align="right" style="display: block;" id ="somelabel"> //this is initially not displayed and will only be displayed when Radio button8 is selected
   <input type="number">//some code here to enter labels and input
  </td>

 </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

but this one is fixed to the window

```html
<div>
 <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="standard-table standard-table-mini" 
 summary="Object Table" style="padding-left: 224px; padding-right: 50px;">
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <th align="center" style="right-padding:10px;"><b>Action</b></th>
     <th align="left"><b>Components</b></th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
<tbody>
 <tr class="even">
  <td align="left" style="width: 550px">
   <div class="field">//some code here to enter radio button as input</div>
  </td>

  <td align="center" style="position: absolute; left: 60%; top: 20%">
   <div class="field">//some code here to populate components when radio button is selected</div>
  </td>

  <td align="right" style="display: block; position: absolute; left: 80%; top: 20%" id ="somelabel"> //this is initially not displayed and will only be displayed when Radio button8 is selected
   <input type="number">//some code here to enter labels and input
  </td>

 </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```